# Update property in object collection with linq

Tags: c#, linq

Have a list of objects with the object structure as following

```
public class Schedule
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Schedule() {}
}
```

Executing a linq query on data I can see properly populated list of objects

```
var schedule = (from d in data 
                select new Schedule
                {
                    ID = d.id,
                    Name = "" 
                }).ToList();
```

later in code I want to change property Name depends on a condition. A few examples I found

```
schedule.ForEach(s => { s.Name = "Condition Name"; });
schedule.Select(s => { s.Name = "Condition name"; return s; });
```

after execution leave Name parameter "null" when I refresh schedule in the watch window.
Can anyone see what's wrong with this?

Looping through collection and trying to change Property doesn't change it either

```
   foreach (var sch in schedule)
   {
       sch.Name = "New name";
   }
```

schedule.ToList()[0].Name == ""

**UPDATE**

.ToList() call in the snippet below is important to make code work.

```
var schedule = (from d in data 
                select new Schedule
                {
                    ID = d.id,
                    Name = "" 
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: To start off, you're doing a select new and only retrieving the ID

Comment: @MrJones missed but in code I select in the object

Comment: Yes, but you're only setting the ID property. You should do something like `(from d in data select new Schedule{ ID = d.ID, Name = d.Name}).ToList()`. Otherwise, `scehdule.Name` will be null.

Comment: The code works - after executing schedule.ForEach() the Name property is updated.  Maybe there is something that you've left out - can you break it down to a sample that compiles in linqpad?  Did you expect the objects in the var data to be affected?

Comment: @Slugart it really works. I left out .ToList() part in var schedule = ...; Brought it in here but left out in my own code. Thanks, your message helped. You can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code works - after executing schedule.ForEach() the Name property is updated. Maybe there is something that you've left out.

Answer (score 4):

Your LINQ query that assigns a value to `schedule` creates independent objects based on the original collection (it effectively clones the objects); changing the properties of the clones does not change the original objects.

Answer (score 3):

LINQ is not the right tool to modify collections, it is a tool to query collections. If you want to modify it you need a loop, for example a `foreach`:

```
var schedule = data.Select(d => new Schedule{ ID = d.id }).ToList();
foreach(var s in schedule)
    s.Name = "Condition Name";
```

If you want to "modify" a collection with LINQ you have to create a new one and assign that to your variable which is inefficient.

Comment: Theoretically should work but leave prop unchanged in the end. Question updated.

Comment: @Maxim: `schedule.ToList()`  creates always a new list.

Comment: My fault with code example, mentioned in the question update. Thank you everyone. Upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Below, you are create new `Schedules` without setting its `Name`.

```
var schedule = (from d in data 
                select new Schedule
                {
                    ID = d.id
                }).ToList();
```

To start, you may want to give the new `Schedules` a `Name`

```
var schedule = (from d in data 
                select new Schedule
                {
                    ID = d.id,
                    Name = d.NameProperty /* Switch out with real name property */
                }).ToList();
```